# Windows 10 not appearing in GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

today I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, I installed it from liveUSB and it is dual booted along with Win 10. **When I restart my computer and grub shows up, there is no Win 10 option.** I tried many things online, boot repair, i tried

```
sudo update-grub
```

and

```
sudo os-prober
```

, but it doesn't show anything at all. I will provide further details when you ak about them, but please keep in mind I'm a beginner when it comes to Ubuntu. Thank you.

Edit: SecureBoot is disabled (which is the output of the command `mokutil --sb-state`), when I type

```
ls /sys/firmware/efi/
```

it shows

```
config_table  efivars  esrt  fw_platform_size  fw_vendor  runtime  runtime-map  systab  vars
```

I don't think I installed Ubuntu in legacy mode, I checked it before but I'm not sure how to check it once again, to be sure.

Edit 2:
The result of a command `cat /etc/default/grub` is

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

the `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=` line was changed by me, original value is `hidden`, I changet so the GRUB would always appeared on restart, before that it didn't even show up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92108/discussion-on-question-by-kihit0mi-windows-10-not-appearing-in-grub).

Comment: When you run `boot-repair` you should save the report and post a link here. Then others can review the report for possible solutions.

Comment: We need to close this post after finishing the pending task(s). @kihit0mi, please appear at chat session.

Answer (score 4):

**Step-1**

It was confirmed that Questioner @kihit0mi's Ubuntu installation has `EFI boot loader` through the following command:

```
$ ls /sys/firmware/efi/
```

Whose output was:

```
config_table  efivars  esrt  fw_platform_size  fw_vendor  runtime  runtime-map  systab  vars
```

**Step-2**

The following command did not yield any output:

```
$ sudo os-prober
```

**Step-3**

The following command was issued to generate `GRUB menu`:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

System was rebooted and an attempt was made to reach GRUB menu through `shift` command. But it was observed that instead of reaching GRUB menu, it ended up on login screen of Ubuntu!

**Step-4**

To reach windows login screen, only way was through `BIOS setup` screen. System was rebooted, and reached `BIOS setup` screen by pressing `del` key. It was observed that there were `three` boot loaders present which are listed as follows:

```
Ubuntu
Windows Boot Manager and 
EFI PXE.
```

After setting up `Windows Boot Manager` to top priority, Windows-10 was logged on successfully!

**Step-5**

Login to Windows 10. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys, type `msinfo32.exe` in `Run` dialog box, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open `System Infomation` window. In the right pane of `System Summary`, you should see the `BIOS MODE` line. If the value of BIOS MODE is `Legacy`, then Windows is booted in `legacy` mode. If the value of BIOS MODE is `UEFI`, then Windows is booted in `UEFI` mode. Questioner @kihit0mi confirmed that the BIOS mode line contained only `UEFI`. That was really good!

**Step-6**

Next, the Firmware BIOS was updated to the latest Version. Refer [How to Check Your Current BIOS Version and upadate it](https://www.howtogeek.com/196916/how-to-check-your-bios-version-and-update-it/).

The following command was given again to generate `GRUB menu`:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

System was rebooted and an attempt was made to reach `GRUB menu` through `shift` command. It was good to observe that this time `GRUB menu` was reached successfully but **the presence of Windows-10 was not found!**

**Step-7**

It was decided to put a `menuentry` into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file which is capable of generating Windows entry into GRUB menu. In order to find out the `disk` and `partition` numbers corresponding to Windows Boot loader, it was rebooted and GRUB menu was reached by pressing 'shift' key. The `grub >` command line was entered, by pressing `c`,  and the following command was given:

```
grub > ls
```

But no output yielded. So The `disk` and `partition` numbers for Windows loader were guessed to be `0` and `2` respectively which are needed for `menuentry` preparation.

```
menuentry "Windows" {
    set root=(hd0,2)
    chainloader +1
}
```

After creating the above `menuentry` in file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, issue the following command to make script `40_custom` file executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Generate GRUB menu with the following command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

System was rebooted and `GRUB menu` was reached by pressing `shift` key. This time  there was a Windows loader found. But while trying to boot, the following error was thrown out:

```
The EFI file path is incorrect error
```

#Step-8

It was attempted again and again with various disk and partition numbers entries in the `menuentry`, but all resulted in the same error message `the EFI file path is incorrect error` after selecting Windows bootloader from GRUB menu.

All these hurdles happened since Questioner @kihit0mi's laptop did not respond to `ls` command from GRUB menu's command line: `grub > ls` .

I tried the same from my desktop's GRUB menu with command `grub > ls` which resulted in the following output:

```
(hd0) (hd0.gpt8) (hd0.gpt7) (hd0.gpt6) (hd0.gpt5) (hd0.gpt4) (hd0.gpt3) (hd0.gpt2) (hd0.gpt1) (hd1) (hd2) (hd2,gpt4) (hd2,gpt3) (hd2,gpt2) (hd2,gpt1) (hd3) (hd3,gpt4) (hd3,gpt3) (hd3,gpt2) (hd3,gpt1)
```

**How to interpret the above output from GRUB `ls` command?**

1. Issue the following command for `(hd0)`:

   `grub > ls (hd0)`

Whose output was:

```
    Device hd0: No known file system detected - Search size 512 B - Total size 117220824 KiB.
```

The output even though showed as `No known file system` but it really represents `/dev/sda` (look at the Total size). If you keep on probing such as `ls (hd0,gpt8)`, `ls (hd0,gpt7)`, and so on until `ls (hd0,gpt1)`, it will display the partitions that corresponding to devices such as `/dev/sda8`, `/dev/sda7` and so on until `/dev/sda1`

The above device `/dev/sda` (120 GB SSD) contains my Ubuntu installation which was shown as `(hd0)` in grub command line. The `gpt1` through `gpt8` represents partitions which are `efi`, `swap`, `/`, `/usr`, `/opt`, `/tmp`, `/var`, and `/home` respectively.

2. Now, issue the following command for `(hd1)`:

`grub > ls (hd1)`

Whose output was:

```
    Device hd1: No known file system detected - Search size 2048 B - Total size 514 KiB.
```

3. Now, issue the following command for `(hd2)`:

`grub > ls (hd2)`

Whose output was:

```
    Device hd2: No known file system detected - Search size 512 B - Total size 976762584 KiB.
```

Although the output was `No known file system` but it really represents `/dev/sdb` (look at the Total size). If you keep on probing such as `ls (hd2,gpt4)`, and so on until `ls (hd2,gpt1)` it will display the partitions that corresponding to devices such as `/dev/sdb4` and so on until `/dev/sdb1`

The above device `/dev/sdb` is my 1 TB HDD with NTFS filesystem which was shown as `(hd2)` in grub command line. The gpt1 through gpt4 represents NTFS partitions which are `unknown`, `CodeWrite`, `ShareMe` and `Warehouse` respectively.

4. Now, issue the following command for `(hd3)`:

`grub > ls (hd3)`

Whose output was:

```
    Device hd3: No known file system detected - Search size 512 B - Total size 244198584 KiB.
```

Though output showed as `No known file system` but it really represents `/dev/sdc` (look at the Total size). If you keep on probing such as `ls (hd3,gpt4)`, and so on until `ls (hd3,gpt1)`, it will display the partitions that corresponding to devices such as `/dev/sdc4` and so on until `/dev/sdc1`

The above device `/dev/sdc` (250 GB SSD) contains my Windows-10 installation which was shown as `(hd3)` in grub command line. The `gpt1` through `gpt4` represents partitions which are  `EFI`, `unknown`, `WindowsOS` and `WinRE` respectively.

#Step-9

**Note:** Questioner @kihit0mi's ubuntu: **no output** for the command `sudo os-probed`. Refer **step-2**.

Again, I tried `sudo os-probed` command from my Ubuntu terminal which resulted in the following output:

```
/dev/sdc1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

A clue was devised from the output of above `os-probed` command. In order to avoid using trial & error method to look for disk and partition numbers, the following search string was incorporated in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
search --set=root --file /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

**Note:** To know more about Grub menu `search` command, [refer this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/search.html#search)

Now the new `menuentry` is capable of searching automatically disk and partition numbers corresponding to windows-10 EFI bootloader, as shown below:

```
menuentry "Windows" {
    search --set=root --file /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

After creating the above `menuentry` in file `/etc/grub.d./40_custom`, the following command was given to generate GRUB menu:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

System was rebooted and `GRUB menu` was reached by pressing `shift` key.

> This time Windows-10 EFI bootloader was selected and booted into Windows-10 system successfully.

#Step-10:

> not yet completed.

The Questioner @kihit0mi's presence is required at `chat` session in order to complete pending task which is the removal of `extraneous` bootloader present in the BIOS setup screen.

Comment: TLDR; If you can't find the right WINDOWS 10 device and boot partition so you can include it in GRUB, follow STEP #9 of this answer.